# How to handle multiple exception raising statements elegantly in Scala

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, functional-programming

I am building a map structure by extracting 30-40 keys from unstructured text rows from messy csv data.  i am extracting using regex on this messy data  row , lot of time those values are not there so  it generates exception,

I put these 40-50  statements in try , catch block and able to parse but issue is  one exception is generated other statement will not be extracted so I started putting each comment inside a try catch block  .

```
try{
statment: 1
statment:2
.
.
.statement 30
}
```

how to handle elegantly such scenario in scala to capture exception in each statement and continue building map structure without puting each statement inside separate try catch block.

```
try{
stat1
}

try{
stat2
}
....
```

Actual Code:-

```
var mp = scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Any]()
try{

// working on json payload
var jsonpayloadstr=  cleanstr.split("\"\\{\"")(1).split(",\"\\[")(0).split("\\}\",")(0).toString
jsonpayloadstr ="{\""+jsonpayloadstr +"}"


var jobj=scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(jsonpayloadstr)

var bdmap=jobj.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]]("Boundary")
bdmap.map(x=>mp=mp+(x._1->x._2))

//batterystatus

var batterystatus= jobj.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, Map[String,Double]]]]("Notification")("Data")("BatteryStatus")
mp=mp+("BatteryStatus"->batterystatus.toInt)

var locationMap= jobj.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, Map[String,Map[String,Any]]]]]("Notification")("Data")("Location")
locationMap.map(x=>mp=mp+(x._1->x._2))

//tagid
var tagId= jobj.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, Map[String,Any]]]]("Notification")("Data")("TagID")
mp=mp+("TagID"-> tagId)

//brechID
var isBreached=jobj.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, Map[String,List[Map[String,Any]]]]]]("Notification")("Data")("SensorData")(0)("IsBreached")
mp=mp+("IsBreached"-> isBreached)
}
catch{
case e: Exception => {
println("Oops none get 123455dsdsd677")
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example of input, exceptions and output? This would help us give the appropriate option.

Comment: If you added some code of what is actually happening in `stat1`, `stat2`, etc it would be easier to understand your problem (one of them should be enough - it sounds like they are quite alike).

Comment: with a Try().getOrElse(other) ?

Comment: Some general advice: use `val` instead of `var` whenever possible. There are other JSON frameworks that are nicer to work with than the one in the standard library e.g. circe or Play JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep on parsing the other variables even if one fails, you can do something like:

```
val batterystatus = Try(...).toOption

val locationMap = Try(...).toOption

...
```

That way you'll have values for everything that parsed correctly and you'll be forced to think about how to handle the ones that didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know a new way from reddit scala forum:-

We shouldn't use exception-based extractions. Put your regexes in a list and map the list with the according extraction function, something like regex => Option[element] and flatten the list after.